# UILocalNotification will work when application is terminated

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

Is UILocalNotification will work when application is terminated?

I do not find the detailed answer for this, if any one have worked UILocalNotification to notify the the mobile when application is termiated.

Your valuable information is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will definitely work according to apple doc.

**The operating system is responsible for delivering local notifications at their scheduled times; the app does not have to be running for this to happen.**

You can refer Apple Doc:-
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification